# Mvc Core 2.0 view components

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am working with mvc core 2.0 project but view component is not working.

I get this error

> InvalidOperationException: Could not find an 'Invoke' or 'InvokeAsync' method for the view component

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "Footer")]
public class FooterViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public ViewViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {      
        var model = new FooterModel();

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the Invoke's return type to `IViewComponentResult`:

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "Footer")]
public class FooterViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        var model = new FooterModel();

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and in the view use it like:`@await Component.InvokeAsync(typeof(FooterViewComponent))`

I am using ASP.Net Core 2.0 and the view components work fine for me.

Comment: I get the same error... The error is duplicated for every razor page that is open in VS.. It doesn't make any sense to me.. My view component classes look identical to yours above.. yet I still get the error..

Comment: Which .Net version are you on, @ZachPainter? Could you share a repo or something?

Comment: I am using .Net 5 currently.. I don't want to waste the time in creating a repro.. If you want to reproduce it just create a new web mvc project with a view component and then render it in the view.. Build the project.. and then open any view.. You should see the error.. A slight difference is that I use the tag helper "<vc:..." syntax vs the url helper..

Answer (score 0):

In my implementation, the Invoke method of the view component must be an Async method and should return a Task as output. This is how it worked for me:

My View Component:

```
public class XTestEntityViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int id)
    {
       // Put your stuff here . . . 
    }
}
```

And you can access it from any view in your application as follow:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("XTestEntity", new { id = 4 })
```

I hope this helps